# duplicate mesh error in blender animation nodes2.1

Tags: animation-nodes

i tried to duplicate mesh using "transform mesh "node,but i faced a issue as the below:[image]

i don't know how to fix the issue?anyone has an idea,thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *Random List* node instead, which populates the a list of arbitrary length with elements. Then you use the *Transform Mesh* node to transform the meshes based on the transforms as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Thank you Omar Ahmad!it works now!

Comment: by the way,how to apply a random color to each mesh via animation nodes?Thank you!

Comment: @charis The easiest method would be to use the *Object Instancer* node to create a number of empty objects, loop over them and the meshes list, output the meshes to the object using the *Mesh Object Output* node, and finally set their color using the *Set Vertex Color* node. I already explained multiple methods to do that here, see those [questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Banimation-nodes%5D+color).

Comment: i am runing into an issue,the set vertext color script node error!"data type wrong",how to fix it?thank you !

Comment: @charis Can't really identify the problem here. Feel free to ask another question.